# Apache server not listening on IPv4 but listening on IPv6

Tags: iptables, apache-httpd, port-forwarding, ipv6, ipv4

We are facing one weird problem on one of our RHEL apache server.

Actually, it is not listening on port 80 from remote hosts. When we locally browse `http://localhost` it is opening default page. When we checked listening port through `netstat`, we found that only `tcp6` interface was listening at `:::80`.
And there was no entry for `tcp`, and that entry should be present there like

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
```

I have tried searching many forums for this issue, but none of the solution suggested worked. In `httpd.conf`, we change `Listen 80` to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`and `Listen 127.0.0.0:80`
but it did not open 80 port to access from remote hosts. IPtables is disabled from the beginning.

How can we set the server to listen on IPv4?

Comment: You could try to set `net.ipv6.bindv6only=0` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and then run `sudo sysctl -p`. This makes the socket listen on both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: `tcp6       0      0 :::80`  Is indicative of the server listening both in IPv4 and IPv6. You can put it back at `Listen 80`. How is the vhost/default vhost configured?

Comment: Check you apache logs for any issues relating to listening on the ip4 address,

Comment: @JohanMyréen I tried using your suggestion, but the result is unchanged. Raman, there are no specific logs generated related to IPv4. Surprisingly, SSH server is running and it is listening on IPv4 and IPv6 port 22. When tried with Listen 0.0.0.0:80 in httpd.conf, the netstat showed tcp entry as
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
but still the port 80 was not accessible from remote hosts.

Comment: Try if the connection succeeds from the local host using the non-localhost IP address. If it is ok, and nothing else that you have tried works, I suspect the problem lies elsewhere (firrewall, etc.) Listening on :::80 should not be a problem, since normally a socket listening on IPv6 also accepts IPv4 connections, unless disabled with `bindv6only=1`.

Comment: Johan, I appreciate your suggestions. I am able to open localhost in the same system. But when I access the server from remote host in the same network, it does not give any response. I have completely removed httpd package with all conf files and reinstalled it but the issue is still there.  IPTables is completely out of frame as we have disabled it from beginning.

Comment: But can you connect in the same system, not using `localhost` (`127.0.0.1` or `::1`) but the IP address of the server? Let's say the server IP address is `10.2.3.4`, try URL `http://10.2.3.4/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
assiduus@localhost:~/httpd-2.4.34$ ./configure --help | grep IPv6
```

> ```
> --enable-v4-mapped      Allow IPv6 sockets to handle IPv4 connections
> ```

```
assiduus@localhost:~/httpd-2.4.34$
```

This is enabled by default when you compile Apache httpd from source. If you used your distribution binary package then apparently this option is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

### Use something similar to this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.domain.com
   ServerAlias domain.com

   DocumentRoot /path/to/your/webroot/
   ...

</VirtualHost>
```

***The "*:80" allows your web server to listen on all ip address on port 80;** however this will not take effect until this newly created virtualhost configuration file is enabled and web server is restarted.

#### Enable your new virtualhost configuration:

```
a2ensite domain.com.conf
```

#### Restart the webserver

```
service apache2 restart
```

#### To verify that web server listens on both ipv4 and ipv6, check with:

```
netstat -plunt |grep ":80"
```

Let me know if this help :)